# Complexity of an Algorithm (wilson test)

Tags: python, complexity-theory

please what is the complexity of Wilson's function in term of O(..):

```py
#fonction calculant le factorielle de n (n!) :

def factorielle(n):
    p=1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        p=p*i
    return p

#fonction testant la primalité de p en utilisant le théorème de wilson :

def wilson(p):
    if factorielle(p-1)%p==p-1:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the complexity of `wilson` function its kind a simple, the complexity based in many times a "instruction" runs in processor, so basicly only loops, afect the complexity, the `wilson` has a complexity of 1 for the if and `factorielle` complexity, so O(1 + O(`factorielle`)).

So, to calculate `factorielle` complexity  we analize the loop, you can see that loop, runs n-1 times, right? So `factorielle` complexity are O(n-1), that makes `factorielle` complexity is O(n), because, its only depends of n to the times that code will run